# Unity: fbx character not responding to animator controller

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, character, fbx

This FBX is not working properly: http://silentrepose.deviantart.com/art/3D-Doctor-Who-Tenth-Doctor-Model-FBX-Version-379066668

I was wondering if someone could check it out an tell me if they can get it to work. I applied the same animator controller to it as another of my characters, and that other character works fine. It has a skeleton and everything so in principle it should work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I figured it out, you have to set animation type to Humanoid if you use humanoid animations.